# Enumerating derived classes in C++ executable

Tags: c++, derived

Suppose you have base class and several derived classes in your C++ app.
You want to enumerate all classes derived from this base without instantiation the derived classes, say to present them to the user in the class name list box. Obviously, the needed information is somewhere in the app. How to retrieve it?

Comment: Just type in the names of the derived classes into some list that you use to initialize the list box? If you want to do this at runtime, it's not doable, C++ does not have reflection.

Comment: "Obviously, the needed information is somewhere in the app." Why is that obvious? It's not even true. C++ doesn't define how a class is represented in an executable, and as just one example of that an optimizer may inline everything so nothing in the executable indicates that the source is even using a class.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a static registrar element. Something like so:

**Base.hpp:**

```
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>
#include <unordered_map>

using typemap = std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::string>;

struct Base
{
    /* ... */
    static typemap & registry();
};

template <typename T> struct Registrar
{
    Registrar(std::string const & s) { Base::typemap()[typeid(T)] = s; }
};
```

**Base.cpp:**

```
#include "Base.hpp"
typemap & Base::registry() { static typemap impl; return impl; }
```

**DerivedA.hpp:**

```
#include "Base.hpp"

struct DerivedA : Base
{
    static Registrar<DerivedA> registrar;
    /* ... */
};
```

**DerivedA.cpp:**

```
#include "DerivedA.hpp"
Registrar<DerivedA> DerivedA::registrar("My First Class");
```

Now any time after `main()` has started you can call `Base::registry()` to get a reference to a map which contains one element per derived class.

Comment: Well, I can do it with the TypeList: at compile time the compiler will register, fill list boxes, etc, retrieving types (classes) from the typelist and using static functions of the classes. But I have to complete the list first, not to use info from the exe file with some magic function.

Comment: Nice solution, but `#include <type_index>` should be `#include <typeindex>`

Comment: is the line in Base.hpp
`Registrar(std::string const & s) { Base::typemap()[typeid(T)] = s; }`
 supposed to read `Base::registry()` instead of `typemap`?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. Most usually you don't known about class names in runtime and you can't get list of your classes. If you don't want to instantiate all needed classes, the only options is to build the list manually.

Comment: It could be done, to some degree, if you wanted to roll your own way of doing it (as in Kerrek's answer).  The real question is whether it's *feasible* to do that, cause standard C++ won't do it for you.  And you'd still be still building the list "manually", cause each class needs to have the code to add itself to the list; you're just letting each class add itself to the list rather than going through and finding classes.